# Creating inline comments within a wordpress blog post

Tags: ajax, wordpress, comments

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to enable users to comment within a blog post in wordpress? For example, in Microsoft word, users can add comments within a article, I'm wondering if the same can be done to a wordpress blog post?

Is there a handy plugin?

What's the best way to go about creating one? Creating overlay with Ajax windows? Any starter code I can pull from?

Has anyone seen this done really well? Surprising that its not more prominent on the web.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing today, but couldn't find anything... it'd be great, if you share if you found something!

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I couldn't find anything useful, so I decided to create my own as well. I'm pretty new to javascript, so its not perfect, but it works... kinda :). Love to hear what you think. http://www.getreadwithme.com/

I think after I asked this question, a ton of sites that support inline commenting poped up.

Comment: Yep, this seems pretty fine tome :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I searched for a plugin, too. There WAS no WordPress plugin. So I've written my own, based on [inlineDisqussions](http://tsi.github.io/inlineDisqussions/).

It's called "Inline Comments", try it: http://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-comments/

Comment: This is super cool Kevin. Thanks for creating it. The screen shots look cool. I'm looking forward to playing around with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, "This plugin has been closed as of December 16, 2018 and is not available for download. This closure is permanent. Reason: Author Request."